# Values in Google Tag Manager are undefined but in console are ok

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I'm pushing values from website to Facebook through GTM, but I don't have access to make code changes on server side.

So every value that I need to send to Fb I have to find using Custom Javacripts in GTM.

I can get those values in console but I don't know why I can't see them in Debug mode. It's always undefined.

Here is one of the code in GTM:

```
function() {
  var prod = document.getElementById("product_addtocart_form").elements.namedItem("product").value;
  return prod;
}
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that line of code works in console, I suspect the code in your function is being fired too early and the elements aren't ready yet.

Make sure your code is not fired until the gtm.dom event is fired, if that still doesn't work then wait until gtm.load is fired.  If that still doesn't work then have a look at when these elements are actually ready (maybe they're created using an AJAX call?).

If the gtm native events aren't late enough, when you know the elements are ready you should fire a custom event into your dataLayer which triggers your tags and repopulates the variables.  Hopefully this will ensure your variables are populated correctly when your tags are fired.

If the elements are loaded using jQuery AJAX you should be able to bind to the ajaxComplete event on the document.  [See the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/).  You would then fire a custom event into the data layer which would trigger the tags that using the data in the variables that should now be populated.  You'd set up a trigger with type=custom event and the value being 'ajax_complete' (or whatever you call your event).

Your code would look something like this:

```
$(document).on('ajaxComplete', function(){
  dataLayer.push({'event':'ajax_complete'});
});
```

If there's multiple AJAX events being fired on a single page then you'll have to write some logic to differentiate between calls and/or make sure you don't fire it multiple times.  There's also a setting in tags in GTM to say 'only fire once per page load' so you could leverage that as well.

Comment: Hey Tom, thanks for helping, yeah the product info is loaded by ajax and I don't have access to the server. Is it possible to do it from GTM instead of changing anything in code on server side?

Comment: Hi Ondrej, you should be able to bind to the ajaxComplete event (assuming you're using jQuery) which then fires in a custom event to the dataLayer to fire the tags that read that variable.  I'll update the answer accordingly.